# Get content between first word and line break

Tags: javascript, select

I would like to get the value of a line between the first word and the line break at the end. for example:

```
foo bar bob
hello hi
```

I want to get "bar bob" by asking for line "foo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

```
var str='foo bar baz'
var estr = str.replace(/^.*? (.*)/i,"$1" )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
var str = "foo bar\n";
str.slice(str.indexOf(' ')+1,str.indexOf('\n')); //returns bar
```